# How to reload layout?

Tags: android

My app lets users change the text and visibility on some TextViews. I want to offer a button that will undo all changes and return the layout to it's original settings.

If you turn the phone from portrait to landscape, it does just that... but how do I trigger it from a button?

Answer (score 0):

You could invalidate the base `View` or call `Activity.setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

> If you turn the phone from portrait to landscape, it does just that... but how do I trigger it from a button?

The `recreate` method of the `Activity` class seems to do just that. Quote from the docs:

> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

An example "configuration change" mentioned above is orientation change, i.e. switching from landscape to portrait or the other way around.

Comment: Blast it, I just noticed that method requires API level 11 :(